# event blur in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I´m trying to add an `EventListener` to my canvas when I lose focus in this canvas.

I have two canvases:

[image]

In the first canvas (at left), I draw a signature, and when change focus to the right canvas, I want the signature drawn on the first canvas to get saved in the server. I know how I can apply the logic to save in the server but I am unable to call the `blur` event in the canvas.

To try this, I'm doing:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("pizarra_cliente");
canvas.addEventListener("blur" , function() { 
  console.log("entro");
});
```

But if I put a debugger in the developer tools, I see the breakpoint is not being fired inside the `blue` event. I tried with the `onfocusout` as well but got the same problem.

Anybody can help me to create an event (`focusOut` or `blur`) to my canvas?

I´m using `blur` because I read that this is an event that should be used in such use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get it with this logic:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
  let c = document.querySelector('#pizarra_cliente');
  var b64Image = c.toDataURL("image/png");
  let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
  let contract = document.getElementById('n_contract').value;
  let installation = document.getElementById('installation_id').textContent;
  
  // upload image canvas to server
  fetch("/installator/saveClientSignature", {
      method: "POST",
      //mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({'image':b64Image, 'contract': contract, 'install': installation})
  }).then(response => response.text())
    .then(success => "")
    .catch(error => "");

})
```

I used `mouseout` event to get event and generate image with canvas data. My image it´s generated ok, and saved in my folder.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works, you can use `window.addEventListener('click', e => {})` and check if the element is other than the canvas. You can use a flag to make it run only once, like:

```
// Create the flag
let leftCanvasFocused = false

// Place this inside your function that guarantee 
// that the user is interacting with the canvas 
// (probably something related to draw)
leftCanvasFocused = true


window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!leftCanvasFocused || e.target.id !== 'pizarra_cliente') return

  leftCanvasFocused = false

  // Your logic goes here
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the `e.target.id` is correct although

Comment: thanks for your response, but your code it´s not usefull for me. you can check my answer more down in this threat. I can solve my problem

Comment: a gambiarra ficou boakkkkkk
I just think the mouseout isn't a good idea because it will trigger the event  lots of time, causing many requests to your API, like, if the user just pass the mouse over and don't react with it.

Comment: You could just implement my idea but changing the event to mouseout, so that way the flag would avoid it calling multiple times

Comment: But if it's just for some tests, your code will work well